# Where is the Silence spell’s description found?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

I do not see the description of the *silence* spell in the PHB, though it is listed as a 2nd-level cleric spell.   What am I missing here?

Comment: I actually had trouble finding it on my first read through too. Don't feel bad about missing it :)

Comment: I've missed spells so many times for the same reason, that I now explicitly look for them at the bottom right of pages. It seems like something that WotC's editors could have tweaked.

Comment: There has to be a joke in here somewhere, about being unable to find the words to cast *silence*.

Comment: I figured that if someone had a hard time finding it, then likely that header and description were not together. Poor formatting..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*[Silence](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/silence)* can be found at the bottom of page 275 of the PHB. Most of description is on page 276.

> For the duration, no sound can be created within or pass through a 20-foot-radius sphere centered on a point you choose within range. Any creature or object entirely inside the sphere is immune to thunder damage, and creatures are deafened while entirely inside it. Casting a spell that includes a verbal component is impossible there.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Good first answer! To save OP the trouble, you may also want to quote the relevant text, as the *silence* spell is in the SRD anyway: https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/silence

Comment: @Nautarch FYI, the PHB and the Basic Rules are not the same document; the page numbers do not match.

Comment: @T.J.L. Yeah, I made an assumption on DNDbeyond saying "Basic Rules, 275" Clearly i shouldn't trust them :)

Comment: @NautArch Yeah, those references are strange. Generally, if it says Basic Rules and gives a page number, the page number is from the PHB or DMG. It's like the Basic Rules flag overrides the actual source flag in that display. They're both there for filtering/sorting purposes, but only the Basic Rules one shows.

Comment: @T.J.L.: I've seen the same thing happen with spells that are in both the EEPC and Xanathar's.